# How do I migrate from the Google Documents List API to the Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

The Google Documents List API is scheduled to be shut down on April 20, 2015 and I need to migrate my code to use the Google Drive API instead. How do I go about this migration?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/migration) determine you how to translate calls to the Documents List API to their corresponding calls in the Drive API. Refer to the Drive API’s documentation for information on how to download libraries and get started.

Be aware that support for older authorization methods ([ClientLogin](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthForInstalledApps), [AuthSub](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/AuthSub), and [OAuth 1.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth_ref)) are also scheduled to be shut down at the same time. If you are currently using these methods please also migrate to [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) at the same time.