# Why are all of my requests to the Google Documents List API failing with a 503 error?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Requests to the Google Documents List API started failing with a 503 HTTP error code. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I migrate from the Google Documents List API to the Drive API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701040/how-do-i-migrate-from-the-google-documents-list-api-to-the-drive-api)

Answer (score 1):

The Google Documents List API was shut down on April 20, 2015 as per the [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/terms).  Please see the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/migration) for information on how to upgrade to the latest API. If the shutdown has impacted a business critical application, please [contact Google for Work Support](https://support.google.com/work/answer/142244).

Comment: Was 503 the best choice? According to w3c, that indicates a temporary condition and the app should retry later in the expectation the problem will have been fixed, imho, a 410 would have been more appropriate. A lot of apps will see the 503 and go into retry loops.

Comment: @pinoyyid, I believe it actually returns 400, not 503.